# Passing param between tasklet and step using jobParameters return null

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I defined simple job. tasklet and then step.

I am trying to pass filePath between those two.

When I reach to the stem the reader is invoked and over there the filePath remain null.

What am I missing?

Job configuration:

```
@Bean
    public Job processFileJob() throws Exception {
          return this.jobs.get("processFileJob").start(downloadFileStep()).next(processor()).build();//.next(pushToKafkaStep()).build();

    }



public Step downloadFileStep() {
        return this.steps.get("downloadFileTaskletStep").tasklet(downloadFileTasklet()).build();
    }


    @Bean
    protected Tasklet downloadFileTasklet() {
        return new DownloadFileTasklet();
    }




@Bean
public Step processor() {
         return stepBuilderFactory.get("processor")
      .<PushItemDTO, PushItemDTO>chunk(1) 
                        .reader(reader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                        ...
                        .build();
            }



                           //here filePath always null!!
@Bean
    @Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ItemStreamReader<PushItemDTO> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters[filePath]}") String filePath) {
        FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<PushItemDTO>();
        itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
        return itemReader;
    }
```

DownloadFileTasklet:

```
public class DownloadFileTasklet implements Tasklet, StepExecutionListener {

   String filePath;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        filePath="someurl";        
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }



    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters();
       // jobParameters.ad
        stepExecution.getExecutionContext().putString("filePath", filePath);
        //Return null to leave the old value unchanged.
        return null;
    }
```

I managed to pass params directly from the jobLauncher while calling this job but when I try to define new param inside the tasklet and wishing to have it in the next step then I get it as null

Thanks you.

As recommened I should use ExecutionContextPromotionListener.

So I added to my java config this:

```
@Bean
    public ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener()
    {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener executionContextPromotionListener=new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        executionContextPromotionListener.setKeys(new String[]{"filePath"});
        return new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
    }
```

However I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'keys' property must be provided
```

I fixed it by changing into  return executionContextPromotionListener;

However filePath is still null.

I also tried to modify my Step declaration this way:

*added the executionContextPromotionListener

```
public Step downloadFileStep() {
    return this.steps.get("downloadFileTaskletStep").tasklet(downloadFileTasklet()).listener(executionContextPromotionListener()).build();
}
```

still null in filePath param

Comment: return new ExecutionContextPromotionListener(); You are returning a new `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` instead of the one you just configured.

Comment: I fixed it. not getting that error. but filePath Is till null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a value to the step's `ExecutionContext` makes it available only to that step.  To make it so that another step can access it, you need to promote that key to the job's `ExecutionContext`.  To do that, take a look at the `ExecutionContextPromotionListener`.  It will promote whatever keys you've configured it to from the current step's `ExecutionContext` to the job's `ExecutionContext` so that they can be accessed from other steps.

You can read more about the `ExecutionContextPromotionListener` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/listener/ExecutionContextPromotionListener.html

Comment: I edited my question as you instructed please see the following error. thank you.

Comment: I think you need to return `executionContextPromotionListener`...not `new ExecutionContextPromotionListener()`  ;)

Comment: Sorry my bad. I fixed it. I dont get that error but I still get null in the filePath param. Maybe I am not defining the stepscope in the right place? ?

Comment: Can you check in the job repository if the value is getting into the execution context?

Comment: I found it. the problem was that since i am passing it via execution Contexnt I needed in the reader configuration to change the spEL expression to: {jobExecutionContext[filePath]}".

Comment: Hi Michael, tried to reach u in some places.. but was hard.. seems like Iam having probs using this implementation while executing jobs in parallel. would be great if you could look at my new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776901/how-to-safely-pass-params-from-tasklet-to-step-when-running-parallel-jobs